Clickhouse primary key and order by keys relation
Does Clickhouse automatically creates sparse primary key indexes on columns defined in ORDER BY clause(without explicitly defining primary key)?
I have a use case where application should be able filter on any varchar column in the table and it will always have a filter on time, so defining an order by clause like ORDER BY(time, col1, col2...) and adding a PARTITION BY toYYYYMMDD(time) should help ?

PRIMARY KEY is prefix for sorting key (ORDER BY)
if PRIMARY KEY missed then ORDER BY will use
adding all fields to ORDER BY doesn't help and will degrade performance
ORDER BY (time)
PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(time)

will enought for 90% use cases
don't use day partioning if you don't have more than 100kk rows per day
look
https://kb.altinity.com/engines/mergetree-table-engine-family/pick-keys/
for details

Thanks for the reply, I have around 2B rows per day so doing PARTITION BY toStartOfDay(time) will make sense I guess ? So we really have to pick beforehand most frequently filtered columns, any other index you can suggest to use on columns that will make filtering on columns fast if I don't want to assume any frequently used columns.

Use columns with low unique values in the primary key. This is a sparse index, which allows quick find data parts and granules which contain data from where conditions.
For 2B rows per day, PARTITION BY toYYYYMMDD(time) is enough
What is your typical time range in WHERE condition?

Typical time range would be a week. Any difference between toYYYYMMDD and toStartOfDay, the return types are different int vs datetime, would that make any difference ? Thanks for the answers.

toYYYYMMDD return 32Bit Integer and parts name will have human readable prefix in /var/lib/clickhouse/data/db/table/YYYYMMDD_<min_block>_<max_block>_<mutation_number>_<level>
for toStartOfDay it return 32bit timestamp timestamp and part prefix will hashed

So using toYYYYMMDD is good for debugging purposes but performance wise both should be same

performance should be same or similar
